# Invalid column name error when column in place

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select rows where the end date is within a range. In my dbo.subscription table I have startdate and enddate columns. When I use startdate, the query runs, but when I use enddate, it says the column name is invalid.

I have tried using '' or "" [] around enddate, I have also tried writing the full name of the column out (dbo.subscription.enddate) but it does not seem to make a difference.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Membershipnumber as Id
               Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY membershipnumber 
                    ORDER BY subscription.enddate DESC) AS rownumber 
         FROM   [dbo].[userprofile] 
                INNER JOIN dbo.subscription 
                        ON userprofile.id = subscription.userprofileid 
                INNER JOIN dbo.subscriptiontype 
                        ON subscriptiontype.id = subscription.subscriptiontypeid

        ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rownumber = 1 and enddate between'2014-12-31' and '2018-12-31'
order by Id
```

Error message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'enddate'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'enddate'.
```

Comment: You don't have a column called `enddate` in the `subscription` table.  It is probably called something similar.  I also note that your sample code does not have 21 lines, so the error message doesn't match the query.

Comment: you haven't projected it in the select list of the cte

Comment: Unless there is a lot more to this query, you don't really need the CTE. You can just make a sub-query that provides the data you need to filter with `rownumber` and `enddate`.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  Also you don't give the structure for your tables. How do you expect people to help you?  Probably read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, depending on the datatype of `enddate`, that query may not be doing what you intend it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final SELECT is a `SELECT FROM cte`.

And `cte` only defines two columns:  `Id` and `RowNumber`.

`enddate` is not defined in `cte`.

Comment: Thanks, this is where I was going wrong! I could have sworn I'd tried that but now it's working so obviously I hadn't